# how can I make my boxblur code work faster?

Tags: c, performance, image-processing, onblur

I have written a box blur code for gray image blur, but it turned out to work much slower than I expected. How can I improve its performance?

```
void boxfilter(int* const srcImg, int* const desImg, const int mask, const int nrows, const int ncols)

{
    LL  *buffer,  *rowImg, *rowPtr;
    int *srcPtr, *desPtr;
    LL pre, sum;
    int row, col, i, len, r;
    const int MAX_ROW_COL = nrows > ncols ? nrows : ncols;
    const int MASK_SIZE = mask*mask;
    LL *headL, *tailL;
    int *head, *tail;
    r = mask / 2;
    rowImg = (LL *)malloc(sizeof(LL)*nrows*ncols);
    buffer = (LL *)malloc(sizeof(LL)*(MAX_ROW_COL + mask));
    len = nrows + 2 * r;
    srcPtr = srcImg;
    rowPtr = rowImg;

    for (col = 0; col < ncols; ++col)
    {
        srcPtr = srcImg + col;
        head = srcPtr + r*ncols;
        tail = srcPtr + (nrows - 2 - r)*ncols;

        for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] = *head;
            buffer[len - 1 - i] = *tail;
            head += ncols;
            tail -= ncols;
        }
        for (i = r; i < len - r; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] = *srcPtr;
            srcPtr += ncols;
        }
        sum = buffer[0];
        for (i = 1; i < mask; ++i)
        {
            sum += buffer[i];
        }

        rowPtr = rowImg + col;
        *rowPtr = sum;
        pre = sum;
        headL = buffer;
        tailL = buffer + mask;
        for (i = mask; i < len; ++i, ++headL, ++tailL)
        {
            *rowPtr = pre;
            rowPtr += ncols;
            pre = pre - *headL + *tailL;
        }

    }

    len = ncols + 2 * r;
    rowPtr = rowImg;
    desPtr = desImg;

    for (row = 0; row < nrows; ++row)
    {
        headL = rowPtr + r;
        tailL = rowPtr + (ncols - 2 - r);
        for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] = *headL;
            buffer[len - 1 - i] = *tailL;
            ++headL;
            --tailL;
        }
        for (i = r; i < len - r; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] = *rowPtr;
            ++rowPtr;
        }
        sum = buffer[0];
        for (i = 1; i < mask; ++i)
        {
            sum += buffer[i];
        }
        *desPtr = sum/MASK_SIZE;
        ++desPtr;
        pre = sum;

        headL = buffer;
        tailL = buffer + mask;
        for (i = mask; i < len; ++i, ++headL, ++tailL)
        {
            *desPtr = pre/MASK_SIZE;
            ++desPtr;
            pre = pre - *headL + *tailL;
        }
    }
    free(rowImg);
    free(buffer);
    return;

}
```

Comment: Please use proper Comments so that others can understand your logic, and atl east mention the name of language, that you have used e.g. C.

Comment: I write it in c programming language, and I write it for an image boxblur.It takes moving average of mask x mask to replace the pixel at its center.First I calculate mask length sum of column direction and store it at rowImg, then I calculate mask length sum of row direction and divide it by mask x mask to get the final answer.@Mrug

Comment: Perhaps make use of an [integral image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) then compute the averages from there.  Once you find the integral image, calculating the area of a region, and ultimately the average is a `O(1)` operation.

Comment: Here you want a profiler. If you post a minimally verifiable, complete example, then I could help you profile it and determine where you're spending the most time.

Comment: @lke Thank you in advance,I have just written a project on Github, maybe  you would like spend some time to help me improve its proformance [bloxblur](https://github.com/xdumengyu/boxblur) or give me some advice on profiler tools